# How to Set Fixed Width of Frameset and centrally Align?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Recently i got one issue while using a frameset in my Jsp Page.

The Code is :

```
<html>

    <frameset rows="8%,*" border="0" >
        <frame src="HeaderUi.jsp" name="header" scrolling="no" style="border-bottom:5px solid #630000;min-height:50px;">
        <frameset cols="215px,540px,250px" border="0" >
        <frame src="webSearchUi" name="search">
        <frameset rows="65%,*" border="0" >
        <frame src="webMainPageUi" name="mainPage" scrolling="yes" style="border:1px dotted #7D7D7D; border-top:0px; border-bottom:0px dashed #5c5c5c">
        <frame src="webEventPanelUi" name="eventPanel" style="border:1px dotted #7D7D7D; border-top:1px solid #7D7D7D; border-bottom:0px dashed #5c5c5c">
    </frameset>

    <frame src="webDataPanelUi" name="dataPanel" style="border-style:solid;border-width:0pt;border-color:66CC33"></frameset>

</html>
```

In this i want to set a fixed width to frameset and display centrally align, Fixed Width Should be 1000px and Centrally align, When i tried this its working properly in IE by using margin auto as ashown in code above, but showing Problem in Chrome and Firefox. Please help me out from this Problem...

Comment: Your code contains three frameset's: rows and cols and again rows. About what you talk? And how about frameset closing tags?

Comment: hi Andrew, I want to just fixed a width of First frameset and showwn centrally.

Comment: First frameset is `frameset rows="8%,*"` or other?

Comment: Yes First frameset is frameset rows="8%,*"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to use next HTML markup:

```
<frameset cols="*,1000px,*" border="0">
  <frame src="about:blank" />
  <!-- Next frameset is centered horizontally and have width:1000px -->
  <!-- Tested in IE8,Chrome13,Opera11.50,Safari5,FF7 -->
  <frameset rows="8%,*" border="0">
    <frame src="HeaderUi.jsp" name="header" scrolling="no" style="border-bottom:5px solid #630000;" />
    <frameset cols="210px,540px,*" border="0">
      <frame src="webSearchUi" name="search" />
      <frameset rows="65%,*" border="0" >
        <frame src="webMainPageUi" name="mainPage" scrolling="yes" style="border:1px dotted #7D7D7D; border-top:0px; border-bottom:0px dashed #5c5c5c" />
        <frame src="webEventPanelUi" name="eventPanel" style="border:1px dotted #7D7D7D; border-top:1px solid #7D7D7D; border-bottom:0px dashed #5c5c5c" />
      </frameset>
      <frame src="about:blank" />
    </frameset>
  </frameset>
  <frame src="about:blank" />
</frameset>
```

Comment: Hi Andrew, again i have one concern, How we should add a background image in this page.

Comment: Sorry, but for me do not known right answer for: how to set _global background_ for all frames. I think that FRAME|FRAMESET in mainly used for splitting page and next loading into each part an other page. Maybe for you is better to use HTML markup with using IFRAME's? But, in any case I dont know. You can made research about it in web or stackoverflow, or add another question with HTML,CSS,javascript tags.